# Pinging Hostname results in reply from 2 different IP addresses

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, ip, ping, ip-address

I have an odd behaviour on my Windows 2008 R2 server, when I ping a hostname of another system, my first reply has a different IP address then the following replies. For example, if I was to ping SERVER1, I get the following result:

```
Reply from 192.168.1.123: Destination host unreachable
Reply from 192.1.1.23: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=126
Reply from 192.1.1.23: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=126
Reply from 192.1.1.23: bytes=32 time=71ms TTL=126

Ping statistics for 10.0.1.23:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0%
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 40ms, Maximum = 71ms, Average = 50ms
```

The hostname has no entry for that IP address, so not sure why I'm getting this response, and if I was try again right after the results would be exactly as I expected.

Any one has an idea why this could be happening

Comment: Frederik Nielsen is absolutely correct about this  line: `Reply from 192.168.1.123: Destination host unreachable`. What I'm curious about is this line: `Ping statistics for 10.0.1.23`.

Comment: @joeqwerty I actually also just noted this.. That does indeed look very strange unless it's just some copy/paste mistake

Comment: Oh, could be...

Comment: Is 192.168.1.123 your default gateway? If you notice, it's a legit reply, it's telling you that 192.168.1.123 is unreachable. Which would lead you to the answer from @FrederikNielsen

Comment: 192.168.1.123 is the host that the OP is pinging from. That's the correct result when the source host doesn't have the destination host's MAC address in it's ARP cache. Frederik's answer is absolutely correct. Additionally, a host would never need to communicate with it's DG when trying to communicate with other local hosts.

Answer (score 5):

The first reply you get is from the device you are pinging from and is probably because of an ARP lookup going on which makes the first ping timeout.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

Makes sense but when I try from another system I don't get that same behaviour. It's actually correct.

Comment: @helpo112: That suggests that the other system already has the MAC address of the system being pinged in it's ARP cache. Clear the ARP cache and try again and see what the results are.

Comment: Could also be that the other host is just doing a faster ARP lookup hence the ping won't timeout before the ARP lookup has finished

Comment: I've cleared the ARP cache, and when I tried again I still seeing the same behaviour. The only thing I noticed was the server has a mounted a iscsi hard drive from a san that has that specific IP. Though doesn't make sense to me why when pinging a hostname it would attempt to fist ping that IP when there's no reference in the DNS for the host name to have that ip.